# When switching viewport, focus stays in last viewport

Tags: compiz, workspaces, ubuntu-mate, workspace-switcher, viewports

I am running ubuntu mate 16.04 and using compiz as windowmanager.

```
$ uname -a
Linux el3 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The problem I have, is that when I switch viewport, the focus stays on the last viewport. So if I start typing, the text will appear on the last viewport.

I have tried looking trough compiz settings, but I cant find a way to fix this.

Ofcourse what I want is: to be able to switch between workspaces and start typing without having to click on the windows each time.

So the question is: How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution in compiz settings.

compiz / General options / Focus & Raise behaviour

Untick the "Click To Focus"